# White page in a wordpress site - plugin or server issue?

Tags: wordpress

This is my site: biodanza-meeting.com
It shows a white page some times and if I reload it then it's working again. Is it a plugin issue? How can I exactly know what the issue is?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this issue. When the page goes white, what appears in the source? Do you get any console errors? Have you turned on debugging?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways to find PHP errors that cause "white pages".

Use Debug in WordPress https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress to check for PHP error(s) that will lead you to a plugin or a code error on the WordPress theme.

If you can't use debug, deactivate all plugins and then activate one by one to find the one that may be causing the error.

Check your hosting account for error logs; the issue could be a hosting problem like a 500 server error other than a PHP error.